# Unselect the selected rows in DataGrid

Tags: vb6

I am maintaining a legacy VB window application. I have datagrid (not datagridview), I select a row by right click, but when i right click on some other rows, that row also shows selected, I just need only one row to be selected, not both. I use DataGrid1.Select(currentSelectedRow), which will select the row. there is second method unselect, but that required row number. When I move the mouse, row number changes. Is there any reset or any other way to reset the datagrid row selection. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all rows in your datagrid and deselect everything accept the newly selected row.